# Changing UIView's center too slow

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, swift, xcode6

I have created 6 UIViews and added them to my main view. Then I added a UIPanGestureRecognizer to my main view. The target for the UIPanGestureRecognizer looks like this:

```
func panned(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed) {
        var ty = sender.translationInView(self.view).y

        for v in self.view.subviews as [UIView {
            v.center.y += ty;
        }

        sender.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view);
    }
}
```

Whenever I pan, the UIViews move, but it laggs pretty much.

How can I fix this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this being run on the main thread?

Comment: yeah i think so, i didn't create a new thread

Comment: By "lags" are you referring to a distance between your touch on the screen and the center of the view?  If so, is that lag more-or-less a consistent distance?

Comment: @RegularExpression the movement of the views is not synchronized with my pan